# Why does edit button only function for row 1 in table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Why my edit button only function for row 1 only in my table?

When I click  other rows it still show data from row 1 but the `id` is changed. 
When I update  row `1` the data updates in the database.

```
//fetch the record to be updated
if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $entry_id = $_GET['edit'];
    $edit_state = true;
    $rec = mysqli_query($db, "select r.room_id, r.room_name, s.time_date, s.entry_id, s.time_exam, s.course_code, s.course_enroll from room r, schedule_entry s where s.room_id = r.room_id");
    $record = mysqli_fetch_array($rec);
    $time_date = $record['time_date'];
    $time_exam = $record['time_exam'];
    $course_code = $record['course_code'];
    $course_enroll = $record['course_enroll'];
    $room_name = $record['room_name'];
    $room_id= $record['room_id'];
    $entry_id= $record['entry_id'];
}

?> 

    <?php 
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="180"><?php echo $row['time_date']; ?></td>
                <td width="70"><?php echo $row['time_exam']; ?></td>
                <td width="200"><?php echo $row['course_code']; ?></td>
                <td width="70"><?php echo $row['course_enroll']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['room_name']; ?></td>

                <td width="70">
                    <a class="edit_btn" href="entry.php?edit=<?php echo $row['entry_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td width="70">
                    <a class="del_btn" href="entryserver.php?del=<?php echo $row['entry_id']; ?>">Delete</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php } }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to run the loop to update the ids,

<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <td> <a class="edit_btn" href="entry.php?edit= 
<?php echo $row['entry_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<?php
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: are there any mistake? theres still same only row 1 can edit

Answer (score 0):

you have to evaluate your syntax, i think `$row['entry_id']` have same value, so you must `var_dump($row)` form know all, like that

```
.... SOME CODE ....
    <?php 
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><? var_dump($row); ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } }?>
```

and after that i think you can solve your problem ...